# Why won't Selenium WebDriver wait until time parameter work using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using the example right from the README.md file here:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = require('selenium-webdriver').By,
    until = require('selenium-webdriver').until;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('firefox')
    .build();

driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr');
driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');
driver.findElement(By.name('btnG')).click();
driver.wait(until.titleIs('webdriver - Google Search'), 1000);
driver.quit();
```

No matter what I set the time (1000 in the example) it will not wait that amount of time. No error is returned.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter is a timeout. It's the maximum time `.wait` will wait for the condition of the first parameter to be satisfied but it will stop waiting as soon as the condition is satisfied.